# How to upgrade MySQL in UwAmp?

Tags: mysql, upgrade, uwamp

I am running UwAmp 3.1.0.  I am trying to upgrade MySQL from is currently installed release (5.7.11) to a newer release (5.7.29). I downloaded the installation zip file and extracted it in a new folder bin\database\mysql-5.7.29. I copied the bin\database\mysql-5.7.11\data directory into bin\database\mysql-5.7.29.
When trying to start MySQL 5.7.29 I get the following message : 
[Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade.

How can I run mysql_upgrade in UwAmp ?

Comment: you cannot just copy the data folder from one version to another. Backup you databases on the old version, then install/activate the new version and Restore the databases in there. But only you databases, not any that you did create

Comment: Or you could try running [mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html) like it tells you to

Answer (score 0):

update : I start from an "empty" MySQL 5.7.11 and want to use 5.7.29 instead. Therefore I am using the in place upgrade method as described in the ref.manual.
I was able to run mysql_upgrade from the Windows command prompt, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I always add MySQL and MariaDB versions (32 bit) as they are released. I simply shut down my DB server, extract the new version package into a new folder within bin/database, then I copy the 'data' folder and the my_uwamp.ini file. Once the copy is completed, I bring up the new  DB server, make sure I can log in with the existing UwAmp passwords, then run the mysql_upgrade command line utility in the new db version 'bin' folder.